# android CursorAdapter and BaseAdapter performance

Tags: android, performance

I need to know which adapter is the best and fast performance between CursorAdapter and BaseAdapter? I always use BaseAdapter when I'm trying to display in ListView. But I know CursorAdapter is updated one and easy to manipulate but not sure which one is better. Or which adapter **(or any adapter else)** should I use to retrieve data from sqlite and display at ListView?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As seen in the [CursorAdapter source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/CursorAdapter.java), `CursorAdapter` is just a thin, convenience wrapper around `BaseAdapter` as you would expect and performs no expensive operations. The vast majority of the time spent displaying items will be in inflating, measuring, and laying out your views which needs to be done no matter what adapter you use. Therefore you should always use the one that provides the closest implementation to your needs. For SQLite database, that is almost exclusively `CursorAdapter`s.